# How to handle parallel pool upon error or exception

Tags: matlab

I am using parallel computing toolbox. When my matlab code terminates due to exception/error while parallel worker is running (e.g. inside an infinite loop), I have to restart the pool via `delete(gcp)` and rerunning `gcp`. Otherwise the following runs always freeze. But restarting parallel pools takes too much time.

This does not happen when I manually cancel the future object `cancel(futureObject)` but I do no want to do this everytime program unexpectedly terminates.

I can cancel `futureObject` at the beginning of the matlab script but the object gets removed when I accidently do `clear all` and there is no way but I have to do`delete(gcp)`. Is there a way to cancel all futureobject automatically (even it is not in the base workspace anymore) everytime I restart matlab script?

Comment: Sounds like a use case for `onCleanup`, maybe. Have you tried using `onCleanup` in the scope of your script to automatically cancel the `futureObject`s?

Comment: How do you accidentally `clear all`? You should never type that, ever! In any case, the simplest solution to your problem is to make your code not throw errors. Take a look at `try`/`catch`, for example.

Answer (score 0):

I just decided to use `try/catch` block with `cancel(futureObject)` on the top-level of the script.